# How to add default params in Nuxt and Axios proxy?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add a default initial param for my proxy. Here's my nuxt config so far

```js
axios: {
  proxy: true,
  params: {
    api_key_token: process.env.API_TOKEN,
  },
},

proxy: {
  '/api/': {
    target: process.env.API_URL,
    pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' },
    logLevel: 'debug',
    // also tried adding params here
  },
},
```

The first solution I tried is to create an interceptor via a plugin but the API key shows in the network tab. I don't want it to get included in the client.

```js
import { Plugin } from '@nuxt/types';

const axiosPlugin: Plugin = ({ $axios }) => {
  $axios.onRequest((config) => {
    config.params = {
      ...config.params,
      api_key_token: 'I_DONT_WANT_THIS_BECAUSE_IT_CAN_BE_SEEN_IN_THE_CLIENT',
    };
  });
};

export default axiosPlugin;
```

I also tried moving the `params` key from `axios` key to `proxy` and got the same return from external API (missing api_key_token).

The log I get is correct `GET /api/user ~> https://external/api`. The only problem here is where to add a default param value in the axios/proxy options object inside the nuxt config.

Comment: Not sure to understand: when will the proxy be used? During the build time on the server or during some client side calls?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. Turns out there's an `onProxyReq` option in the proxy key config.

```js
proxy: {
  '/api/': {
    target: process.env.API_URL,
    pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' },
    logLevel: 'debug',
    onProxyReq: (proxyReq) => {
      proxyReq.path += '?api_key_token=' + process.env.API_TOKEN;
    },
  },
},
```

The solution ain't that good but for now, it is working.

Source: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/issues/184

Comment: Is this still visible to the client?

Comment: @Mulhoon not visible.